# how to prove properties of order symbols using formal definitions?

Tags: proof-writing, asymptotics

how to prove using formal definitions of O and o?

o(f) + O(f) = O(f)

where Big O = O, little o = o and f is a function

Comment: Do you even know the definitions? Because it is quite obvious from them.

Comment: I do not know. Could you write?

Comment: Why are you trying to prove things about big O and little o *if you don't even know the definitions*?? Go learn the definitions. Look them up in Wikipedia if you can't find them elsewhere. THEN look into proving things about them.